# JGit requires authentication but git on the commandline doesn't

Tags: java, git, jgit

I'm implementing a happy path `git push` with JGit.

Situation:

- I have a git repository (local) that links to a remote git repository (origin)
- git on my machine has been configured with `git config --global credential.helper wincred`
- The first time I do an operation that requires authentication (such as git push), it asks for username/password and I input them manually.
- The second time, it doesn't

In this happy path, I assume that git credentials are already configured and these credentials are cached.

With JGit, this code fails: `git.push().call();` 

Isn't that statement equivalent to `git push` from the command line?

If git push from the command line succeeds, then why does JGit fail with "Authentication is required but no CredentialsProvider has been registered"?

If what I am looking for is not possible, I might just fork a process! 
What do you advise?

Note: the remote could support both ssh or https. In the case I describe above, it supports only http and the remote url = `http://<user>@<git-server>/.../<git-repo>.git`

Comment: [This bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=441198) looks like it answers your question - jgit doesn't have support for `credential.helper`